# Use ffmpeg to upload directly to s3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have PHP script that I am using to convert files to the mp3 extension. First the user uploads the file to an EC2 server. From there, can I use ffmpeg to process a file and directly upload it to S3?

How do I upload a file, process/convert with ffmpeg and upload to an s3 bucket?

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to do it in two steps?

Comment: Should I output the file to a local destination on my EC2 instance first? Then do I upload that file to an S3 bucket and delete the local one? It just seems to take a lot more steps, but that's the way I am doing it now

Comment: The thing is that if the uploading fails for some reason then you'll need to start all over, whereas doing it in two steps will allow you to recover from an upload failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your s3 onto ec2 instance and then give the path to the s3 mounted folder. [Atleast on linux]. s3fs and other utilities allow you to do this. So it is feasible. however your write speed might be limited here. But if you are not doing very large files or not bothered by the performance hit to the extent this is fine.